# Spark load to Hive

Tags: apache-spark, records

I am thinking of this logic:

```
val cnt = sc.textFile("/home/user/cust_acc.txt").map(line => line.split("|")).count.toInt///find number of rows

for(i<- 1 until cnt )

val v_arr1 = sc.textFile("/home/user/cust_acc.txt").map(line => line.split("|")).take(i).count //count array elements
case when v_arr1 =7 then execute

case class Person(name: String, age: String,age1: String,age2: String,age3: String,age4: String,age5: String)
val splitrdd = sc.textFile("/home/user/cust_acc.txt").map(line=>line.split("|")).map(p => Person(p(0), p(1),p(2),p(3),p(4),p(5),p(6))).toDF()
registerTempTable("df")
process thru sqlContext.sql("processing")
then write append to hdfs

case when v_arr1 =6 then execute

case class Person(name: String, age: String,age1: String,age2: String,age3: String,age4: String)
val splitrdd = sc.textFile("/home/user/cust_acc.txt").map(line=>line.split("|")).map(p => Person(p(0), p(1),p(2),p(3),p(4),p(5))).toDF()
registerTempTable("df")
process thru sqlContext.sql("processing")
then write append to hdfs
```

......
.....

Somehow the code I am working is not fine. Can anyone guide me here?

Comment: 900 million records in hdfs of different fields, not same fields. The permutation as I can see is that we can have 7,6,5,4 fields.

Comment: Oops, I found out the way. I wrote UDF.